# Extend timeout for some trades in pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading

I have this code block written in pinescript:

```
closePosition(timeoutS)=>
    if strategy.opentrades > 0
        for i = 0 to strategy.opentrades-1
            if time - strategy.opentrades.entry_time(i) >= timeoutS*1000
                entry = strategy.opentrades.entry_id(i)
                qty = strategy.opentrades.size(i)
                strategy.close(entry, comment = str.format("Close {0}-{2} by timeout {1}s", entry, timeoutS,i),qty = qty)

closePosition(7200)
```

Change the code so that if a trade is in profit, extend the timeout for that trade.

When a position is open, it can be a loss or a profit, and this code does not care about it, but I want to modify it so that when time reaches timeout, look at position status, and if it is in profit, it extends timeout once again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `strategy.opentrades.profit()` function to see if the trade is in profit and if it is, set a new timeout value.

```
strategy.opentrades.profit(trade_num) → series float
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, but I am not sure. Give me your opinions. It is a bit challenging, I agree.

```
var int[] whitelst = array.new_int()

closePosition(timeoutS) =>
    if strategy.opentrades > 0
        for i = 0 to strategy.opentrades - 1
            idt = strategy.opentrades.entry_time(i) 
            if strategy.opentrades.profit(i) > 0 and not whitelst.includes(idt) and time - strategy.opentrades.entry_time(i) >= int(timeoutS) * int(1000)
                whitelst.push(idt) 
            if time - strategy.opentrades.entry_time(i) >= int(timeoutS) * int(1000) and not whitelst.includes(idt)
                entry = strategy.opentrades.entry_id(i)
                qty = strategy.opentrades.size(i)
                strategy.close(entry, comment = str.format("Close {0}-{2} by timeout {1}s", entry, timeoutS, i), qty = qty)
            if time - strategy.opentrades.entry_time(i) >= int(timeoutS) * int(1000) * 2 
                entry = strategy.opentrades.entry_id(i)
                qty = strategy.opentrades.size(i)
                strategy.close(entry, comment = str.format("Close {0}-{2} by timeout {1}s", entry, timeoutS*2, i), qty = qty)

closePosition(7200)
```